# Webstorm 11 [TypeError: Buffer is not a function] in debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I updated webstorm from version 9 to version 11.0.2. And I have many errors [TypeError: Buffer is not a function] in console when I start to debug my project.
For example error occured on this line:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

and in this line:

```
var crc = require('crc').crc32;
```

This errors occured only in debugger. If I run my project using console everything is fine.

I use nodejs 5.2.0

Comment: Can you try it with node v5.1.1 and/or v4.2.3?

Comment: with node v5.1.1 debugger works well. Thank you very much!

Comment: You may want to report the problem [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/new) as I'm not sure this particular issue is already known. However there have been other debugger-related issues with v5.2.0.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug from WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEA' NodeJS plugin. An [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19448) as been created for this debugger bug. The problem is recent and should be fixed soon.